# Creating an iterable data struct from another efficiently

Tags: scala

```
class Vehicle(name:String, model:String, owner:String, color:String )
class Model(name:String, year:Int, active:Boolean)
class Person(name:String, age:Int, origin:String)
```

Obviously , there id a 1-1-1 relationship between the 3 entities.

I have a `Seq[(Vehicle,Person)]` that may potentially have 100k+ entries.
I need to convert this into a `Seq[(Vehicle,Person,Model)]` with a lookup into a model collection Seq[Model],for every vehicle - based on model name.

Wha is the most memory/performance effective way to do this.

Comment: If it was 1-1 correspondence then I guess `Map`. But it's "obviously" 1-n: `Vehicle` has `owner` field, but `Person` doesn't have `vehicle` field, so 1 person can have 0, 1 or multiple vehicles. Same with `Vehicle` and `Model` (model can have 0, 1, ... vehicles). So it would be more like `Map[Model, Set[Vehicle]]` and `Map[Person, Set[Vehicle]]` to get vehicles for model/person, and `Map[Vehicle, Model]` + `Map[Vehicle, Person` to find the model/person for a vehicle.

Comment: If your lookup function is fast enough, you only need to `map` the original sequence. BTW, you may also consider not needing to fit all the data in memory and use lazy transformations using some stream data type.

Comment: You are mapping it the wrong way. You already have people and vehicles, just need to add models. So, what you need is `Map[String, Model]`

Comment: With all the constraints you included the only thing that's left to decide is picking right collection types for the lookup and for keeping the final data and for that this link will be useful https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html